# Taylor series: expand and state the range of $x$

Tags: taylor-expansion

(ii)    Expand the expression
$$
\dfrac{ 3\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{1-x}
$$
in ascending powers of $x^3$ and state the range of values of $x$ for which the expansion is converging.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Use the expansion
$$(1+y)^a=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{a}{k}y^k+o(y^n)$$
which holds for $|y|<1$.
Hence
$$\sqrt{1+4x^2}=(1+4x^2)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2}(4x^2)+o(x^3)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=(1-x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+o(x^3).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not worried about the expansion more about the range

Comment: I can do the (1-x)^-1 not the sqrt one

Comment: Its fine Ive realised how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{3\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{1-x}\right](0)\ne 0$, that function cannot be expanded in a power series in the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x^3)^k$ (i.e., what you ask cannot be done).